# meaning of boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp in boost::shared_ptr dereference

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the following code to list a directory:

```
for ( const auto& fileEntry : boost::make_iterator_range( boost::filesystem::directory_iterator( some_directory ), {} ) )
{
    const boost::filesystem::path tmpFullName = fileEntry.path();

    if ( boost::filesystem::exists( tmpFullName ) &&
        boost::filesystem::is_regular_file( tmpFullName ) &&
        (boost::filesystem::extension( tmpFullName ) == ".doc") )
    {
        processFile( tmpFullName.string() );
    }
}
```

I have seen the following error sporadically

> /boost/1.47.0/include/boost-1_47/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:420:
>   T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T =
>   boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

In my code, I do not define anything boost shared_ptr instead I only use std::unique_ptr.
Thus, I assume the potential issue is with the above list function.

Can someone please double-check this function and see whether there is any potential issue here?

Comment: Does the problem occur with the latest version of Boost?

Comment: Due to internal reasons, I cannot use the latest version of Boost

Comment: Note that you can use the shorter version without making a range explicitly: `for ( const auto& fileEntry : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator{ some_directory } )`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `directory_iterator_increment()` (in `operations.cpp`) contains the following code:

```
1940: if (temp_ec)
1941: {
1942:   it.m_imp.reset();
1943:   if (ec == 0)
1944:     BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(
1945:       filesystem_error("boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::operator++",
1946:         it.m_imp->dir_entry.path().parent_path(),
1947:         error_code(BOOST_ERRNO, system_category())));
1948:   ec->assign(BOOST_ERRNO, system_category());
1949:   return;
1950: }
```

Line 1946 dereferences `it.m_imp` after it has been reset at line 1942.  This would cause the observed behaviour.

EDITED TO ADD:

This is fixed in later versions: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5900

Answer (score 0):

What compiler are you using? It could be the c++ library version you are using is mismatching with boost's.

Comment: gcc version  is 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Boost uses `shared_ptr` internally in the directory iterators, because "shared_ptr provides shallow-copy semantics required for InputIterators," (boost/filesystem/operations.hpp, line 924, from Boost v1.61). In v1.61 there is an explicit assertion for the case of dereferencing an `end` iterator, but maybe v1.47 just counted on the assertion of the `shared_ptr` dereferencing.

My guess is that the iterator is invalidated somewhere. Any chance that the directory doesn't exist in those cases? Maybe a change to the directory from another thread/process happens?

BTW, v1.61 includes `begin()`/`end()` functions for enabling the usage of `directory_iterator` in a range-based for loop. Maybe it wasn't in v1.47, but if it was, I'd count on it instead of using `make_iterator_range()` explicitly.

Comment: There is no chance that directory does not exist b/c it has been checked at the start of program. Assume the director is changed and doesn't exist, I still need to figure out way to prevent the application from crashing.

Comment: In which line you get the assertion?

Comment: /boost/1.47.0/include/boost-1_47/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:420

Comment: It doesn't give the line inside my code. Instead, it dumps the message posted in the original question and then crashes. Also I am not able to find a workflow to repeat the problem. The issue hardly happens. But I know the problem does exist and want to fix it.

Comment: Debugger, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `{}` in the first line is producing the end iterator that you expect?

Try explicitly constructing it and see if it makes a difference:

```
boost::make_iterator_range(
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator( some_directory ),
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator()  // instead of '{}'
)
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, then it should fail every time I run the code.

Comment: That depends on specifically how it "doesn't work" (if indeed it doesn't) - especially if it results in UB.  Have you tried it?